# How do I create four custom folders on the root (C:\) of the target machine in a VS 2005 setup project?

Tags: .net, setup-project

I need to create four custom folders that are on the root of the target machine (C:\Folder1).  I've created folders and placed files in .NET setup projects in the past, but I'm usually using pre-configured locations such as 'application folder' 'common files folder', 'program files folder', etc.  I can create a custom folder, but how can I make it point to 'C:\' and then add my four folders to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by adding a Custom Folder and set the properties as :

**(Name):** Root

**DefaultLocation:** C:\

**AlwaysCreate:** True

After this Custom Folder is created, right-click the folder and select Add > Folder.

The tree should look like:

File System on Target Machine

- Root

  - New Folder #1
  - New Folder #2
  - New Folder #3
  - New Folder #4

Comment: That seems like a viable solution.  I just implemented this and when I ran the setup, it didn't create the folders.  The other fields are condition (which is blank), property is set to 'NEWPROPERTY1', and transitive is set to 'false'.

Comment: Is it a problem that there won't be any files in this folder hierarchy?

Comment: Did you set 'AlwaysCreate' to True on your subfolders?

Comment: No, I hadn't set the 'AlwaysCreate' option on the subfolders.  That worked.  I'm accepting your answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

To make a local root folder relate
right click file system
add-customer folder
Rename it like Root name
always create = true

set propriety to NEWPROPERTY1
default location = C:/

now
right click the Root Folder you created
add - Folder (all folder you need to create)
be sure you active always create to True